# Проблема с аргументами

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть вот такой код, который в многопоточном режиме обрабатывает сразу несколько JSON файлов в XLS:

```
import json
import os
import xlwt
import threading

def json_to_xls(i):
    wb = xlwt.Workbook()
    ws = wb.add_sheet('sheet 1')
    ws.write(0, 0, 'Type:')
    ws.write(0, 1, 'Project Id:')

    with open(i, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fh:
        data = json.load(fh)

    l = 1
    for d in data:
        ws.write(l, 0, d.get('type'))
        ws.write(l, 1, d.get('project_id'))
        l += 1

    wb.save(i + '.xls')

files = os.listdir()
thread_list = []
value = 0

for i in files:
    json_file = i.endswith('.json')
    if json_file == True:
        t = threading.Thread(target = json_to_xls, name = value, args = i)
        value += 1
        t.start()
        thread_list.append(t)
        print(i)
        converter_json(i)

for t in thread_list:
    t.join()
```

Такую конструкцию создания поток использую постоянно и она никогда не подводила, до этого момента, выдает ошибку:

```
    Exception in thread 1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Thommy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Thommy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: json_to_xls() takes 1 positional argument but 21 were given
```

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, полную трассировку ошибки.

Comment: @nomnoms12 Exception in thread 1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Thommy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Thommy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: json_to_xls() takes 1 positional argument but 21 were given

Comment: Кстати, не нужно сравнивать логический тип с `True`. Вы можете использовать условие вот так: `if json_file:`

Comment: @nomnoms12 да привычка просто, но спасибо, буду стараться больше такого бреда не писать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы неправильно указали аргументы при создании потока.

Ожидается кортеж. В Вашем случае передавалась строка, поэтому он посчитал, что каждый символ строки - отдельный аргумент.

Попробуйте это:

```py
t = threading.Thread(target=json_to_xls, name=value, args=(i, ))
```